# Split String With Multiple Delimiters and Retain Delimiters

Tags: sql-server

I need to split a string into rows at specific word boundaries. The catch is that I need to maintain the specific word boundary which triggered the split because later, I want to recombine the rows and see the delimiter. I'm updating an existing function which looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(8000) = 'AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox'
DECLARE @Delimiters varchar(100) = '%[ ,-/]%'

;WITH 
    [Elements] AS
    (
        SELECT
            1 AS Position
            , 1 AS StartOffset
            , PATINDEX(@Delimiters, @Input) - 1 AS EndOffset
            , @Input AS Input
            , SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX(@Delimiters, @Input), 0) - 1, 8000)) AS Word
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            Position + 1 AS Position
            , EndOffset + 2 AS StartOffset
            , EndOffset + ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX(@Delimiters, SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset + 2, 8000)), 0), LEN(@Input) - EndOffset) AS EndOffset
            , Input
            , SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset + 2, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX(@Delimiters, SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset + 2, 8000)), 0) - 1, 8000)) AS Word
        FROM 
            [Elements]
        WHERE 
            EndOffset BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@Input) - 1
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Elements]
```

Giving me:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------+
| Position | StartOffset | EndOffset |            Input            | Word  |
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------+
|        1 |           1 |         2 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox | AC    |
|        2 |           4 |         5 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox | DC    |
|        3 |           7 |         6 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox |       |
|        4 |           8 |        10 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox | The   |
|        5 |          12 |        16 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox | Quick |
|        6 |          18 |        17 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox |       |
|        7 |          19 |        23 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox | Brown |
|        8 |          25 |        27 | AC/DC, The Quick, Brown Fox | Fox   |
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------+
```

This breaks it up nicely but omits the "/" and "," rows from the result set. I do have a Numbers table I can bump against and I'm pretty flexible about how this can be accomplished.

I COULD brute force my way through it with a loop but this seems too barbaric.

Comment: Please don't spit in this direction...

Comment: Your splitting logic is not handling 2 delimiters together very well. You may be better off just breaking the whole thing up (you can use a numbers table for this), checking if each char is a delimiter or not, and then building words similar to the current logic.

Comment: @JNK can you provide an example splitting against a known list of delimiters using a numbers table?

Comment: @JohnHurrell they're all over the place (search for string splitting SQL numbers table) but the basic idea is to use the numbers table to index into every character of the string efficiently.

Comment: @JNK: Thanks anyway, but all the examples I know of split a string using a numbers table against a single comma delimiter. I'm now working on modifying what I need to do by using some logic where the character at a position NOT LIKE '[a-z]' hoping that I can prevent having to specify a ton of delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you were close, you just have to amend the logic when the "split" is on a delimiter or not. The code gets ugly, but you don't have to brute force it. If I really worked on it, I might be able to make it "prettier". I was just quickly building off what you'd created.

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(8000) = ',AC/DC,,The Quick, Brown Fox-Hound'
DECLARE @Delimiters varchar(100) = '%[ ,-/]%'

;WITH 
    [Elements] AS
    (
        SELECT
            1 AS Position
            , 1 AS StartOffset
            , PATINDEX(@Delimiters, @Input) - 1 + case when  PATINDEX(@Delimiters, Left(@Input,1)) = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS EndOffset
            , @Input AS Input
            , SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX(@Delimiters, @Input), 0) - 1 +case when  PATINDEX(@Delimiters, Left(@Input,1)) = 1 then 1 else 0 end, 8000)) AS Word
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            Position +1 AS Position
            , EndOffset + 1 AS StartOffset
            , EndOffset + ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX(@Delimiters, SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset+1 , 8000)), 0) -  case when  PATINDEX(@Delimiters, SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset+1 , 8000)) = 1 then 0 else 1 end  ,datalength(Input)-endoffset) EndOffset
            , Input
            , SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset+ 1 , ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX(@Delimiters, SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset+1 , 8000)), 0) -  case when  PATINDEX(@Delimiters, SUBSTRING(Input, EndOffset+1 , 8000)) = 1 then 0 else 1 end  ,datalength(Input)-endoffset)) AS Word
        FROM 
            [Elements]
        WHERE 
            EndOffset BETWEEN 1 AND datalength(@Input)-1 
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Elements]
```

Comment: The requirements changed so we were unable to use this solution but it works and does what it's supposed to so I'm marking this as answered. Thanks for the code.